# Making a rectangle with size 80% of screen in an app

Tags: android

I have to make a rectangle with size 80% of original screen size of an app. Can I do it by only modifying the xml file?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ConstaintLayout` and apply `android:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.8"` attribute for the rectangle inside ConstaintLayout

Comment: See sample at https://wajahatkarim.com/2018/04/percentage-width/height-using-constraint-layout/

Answer (score 0):

In your xml of rectangle use:

```
 android:layout_margin="15dp"  ///this will work. U can play with the margin value to get the desired answer
```

Upvote the answer if useful!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline6"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline5">


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.1" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.9" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.1" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.9" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

the internal layout always left 10% of the screen for every side.
Hope it helps.

## EDIT

add dependency in your build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    ...
}
```